# What software created this graph?

Tags: graphics, charts, drawing

Can anyone recognize what software could have been used to create a graph like this?

[image]

I'm looking for something that could produce the same type of arrows.

Comment: It may be impossible to be sure....

Comment: I would have voted to close as either too-localized or off-topic, on the lines of http://meta.superuser.com/questions/1183/questions-asking-for-manual-identification-of-fonts

Comment: @Hello71: It's a close call, and I think it's a pretty silly type of question.  Regardless, I'm not going to vote closed right now as, unlike font indentification, I can't come up with a better place for a user to ask this.

Comment: Pretty lousy arrows. I'd avoid whatever software made them, unless it allows customization of head size, etc. not shown in that image.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Microsoft Visio

Comment: +1 - That is my guess.... but many packages may have.

Comment: @Frank Are you aware of any other?

Comment: Do you _know_ this is done with Visio?  Can you provide some reference to this shape-set in Visio?

Comment: It's possible to create this in many programs. I would chose Visio because it can create those arrows quickly and easily. The other shapes are just letters/numbers, squares, and circles. The gears could be found as a free downloadable "stencil" - what Visio calls shape packs

Answer (score 0):

i suspect paint.net could - but those arrows are PRETTY generic